# Query fails on presto-cli for a table created in hive in orc format with data residing in s3

Tags: hive, orc, presto

I set up an Amazon EMR instance which includes 1 Master & 1 Core (m4 Large) with the following version details:
EMR : 5.5.0
Presto: Presto 0.170
Hadoop 2.7.3 HDFS
Hive 2.1.1 Metastore

My Spark app wrote out the data in ORC to Amazon S3. Then I created the table in hive (`create external table TABLE ... partition() stored as ORC location 's3a"//'`), and tried to query from presto-cli, and I get the following error for query `SELECT * from TABLE`:
Query 20170615_033508_00016_dbhsn failed: com.facebook.presto.spi.type.DoubleType

The only query that works is:
`SELECT COUNT(*) from TABLE`

Any ideas?

Comment: how did you reorder the file? Did you query using the hive catalog? ORC shouldn't have a order issue. Could you please explain.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Found out the problem. The column orders when it was stored as orc did not match those when table was created in hive :)!!!

Comment: AFAIK, `ORC` files already [incorporate `schema` information](https://orc.apache.org/docs/types.html); I'm therefore confused as to why a mere *re-ordering of columns* caused your queries to fail (I would expect this in case of `CSV` files but not ORC)

Comment: I agree. @iyerland could you please explain